# How to build an application with GTKMM3 in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion, gtkmm

4 day I try to assemble the application using GTKMM3, but it does not work out. I'm trying to collect in Clion (used for CMAKE). He does not find the GTMM, although the GTMM is in C:/. The GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIR variables are empty

Errors:
http://pastebin.com/xKsZgsYQ
CMakeList:
http://pastebin.com/tWtwx3C6

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk372andgtkmm360forwindows/ - libs GTKMM, which I use

Comment: It's important!